# Can we use Expectiminimax for the card game with 2 teams?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax, game-theory, expectiminimax

I am going to implement Rang Card Game. it is played between 4 players with 2 on each team? The game will be played between 1 human and 3 ai agents. I want to ask is it possible to implement this game using Expectiminimax, if yes then are we going to put two players as max and the other two as min?

Comment: Why not. Seams to be the canonical approach. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I just needed to confirm it, cause i am not very good in AI